# Extension of Rolle's Theorem for twice differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function that is twice differentiable with $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < b$. If $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3)$, then I want to show that there exists a point $x_0 \in (a, b)$ with $f''(x_0)=0$. I thought about using Rolle's Theorem in this case. All I think I have to do is to show that there exists two distinct points $c, d \in (a, b)$ with $f'(c) = f'(d)$. But I'm not sure whether it is possible, or where I should start on this. Is anyone able to give me a hint on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist $t\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f'(t)=0$ and There exist $s\in (x_2,x_3)$ such that $f'(s)=0$. Apply Rolle's Theorem to the interval $[t,s]$.